Is it possible to "remaster" old game's pixelated 2d animations in automatic ways?
Below is an example from an old 2d game, which targeted 1024x768 resolution at 10-15 fps with 8 directions.
Animations are purely image sequence with timestamp, without bones.
(animated WebP with transparent background) https://bashify.io/i/yswaFl
I want to effectively up-scale it spatially + temporally + get more directions.
I don't think it is possible without NN, so I posted the question here.
Any of these ways would be good:

Keep as 2D images: up-scale it spatially + temporally + view synthesis.
I did some random googling, and only found one related to generate more directions:  SyncDreamer.
Since it is single image, I assume extra efforts must be taken to ensure temporally consistent animation.
I did not find acknowledged model for temporal interpolation, but found examples of badly failed ones.
Generate 3D mesh model: model + texturing + animation.
Is there any model that can generate animation from image sequences?
There are quite a few image-to-model services gated behind paywall.
I tried the few ones with free trial (of single image), and pixelated images doesn't seem to give good model + texturing.
Generate voxel model + animation.
I have no idea how high resolution voxel is edited, rendered and animated.
Other ways I never heard of.

